# Error using Twig with Doctrine record

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-1.2, twig

I am trying to use `Twig` templates to display some objects fetched with `Doctrine 1`. I face an issue when accessing a relation declared with `hasMany` in the `setUp` function of the `User` class. In my PHP code I can do a `$user->Instance` without any issue but if I pass `$user` to the template and try to do a `user.Instance` an exception is raised:

```
Doctrine_Record_Exception' with message 'Unknown method User::Instance'
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks,

PS: using `user.get('Instance')` seems to work though I would of course prefer to avoid it

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this you have to define all the getters you want to call in the template because doctrine uses "magic methods" (__call()-method) to provide you the getters and setters.

E.g. for property "firstname":

Twig checks whether the method "getFirstname" exists but there is no method "getFirstname" defined in your model.

Here you find a patch to tell doctrine to genrate the getters and setters:
http://coolsoft.altervista.org/en/blog/2009/03/how-make-symfonydoctrine-generate-accessors